# Python pygame freezes during music playing

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I am building a simple mp3 player.  I have it now so it plays a sound fine when I enable the function, but the gui temporarily freezes while waiting for the sound file to finish.  I would like to be able to hit stop, exit, etc while the file plays.  Any advice?

```
def Play():
    soundfile = 'test.wav'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(soundfile)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():

        for event in events:

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.Q:
                    sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                 print "mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
```

Comment: As I understand it `mixer.music.play` is async, so it the program isn't freezing because the sound is playing. It would seem the reason your program is "freezing" is because you in your own loop `while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():`  waiting for it to finish. If you want something to happen while it is playing, put it inside that while statement, or take the while statement out.

Answer (score 0):

When pygame.event.get() is not being called, the game window will freeze. Since you're calling pygame.event.get() outside of your while loop, the window event queue is only getting flushed once. The simple solution is to just replace the events variable with pygame.event.get() directly inline so that it gets called continuously while get_busy() returns true.

In general for these situations, a better solution would be a little refactoring where you have pygame.event.get() called once centrally in your program and instead of calling a function called Play() that handles managing your event queue, you instead have a function called handlePlayForOneFrame(list_of_relevant_events_this_frame).